# MS Access: Report opened with acDialog doesn't return control when made invisible

Tags: ms-access

If you open a Form with acDialog (using DoCmd.OpenForm), execution of the calling routine will halt execution until the form is either closed or made invisible.  Using the invisible method is useful to let the calling routine harvest data off the form.

I had hoped that Reports would work the same way.  That is, opening a report using acDialog with DoCmd.OpenReport.   Unfortunately, when the report is made invisible, it disappears but does not return control to the calling routine.

Is this a bug in Access?  Does anyone know of a way to make this work?  My alternatives to pass data back to the calling routine are all ugly.  For example, use global variables or have the report insert data back to its caller before closing (this requires having the report know its caller).

Comment: Reports aren't really designed for data input, so I wouldn't call this a bug. -- You can use `OpenArgs` to tell the report about its caller.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, reports generally don’t do much interaction, and they don’t generally need to return data (what data going to change in a report?).

However, you can adopt a relative “clean” means to return values to the calling form, and this works well for forms, and would also work reasonable well for reports (but as noted, it seems rather rare that a report would return data since they tend to not change anything).

So what you do is in the forms on-load (or report) is grab a reference to the calling form like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public frmPrevious     As Form

Private Sub Command67_Click()
   ' this is our report close button code
   ' we can set, call, or do ANYTHING to the calling 
   ' form - including setting controls or running code

   frmPrevious!Text18 = Now()
   frmPrevious.Refresh
   Call frmPrevious.MyCodeToRun

   DoCmd.Close

End Sub

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

   Set frmPrevious = Screen.ActiveForm

End Sub
```

So the above is the code in the report. Note that we can set any value in the calling form, set any control, run any code, or even “refresh” the calling form.

So you are free to grab values from the previous form, you are free to return values, set controls, or run code, or use ANY property or method in that calling form.

In fact, as a coding standard, I very often create an frmPrevious value for “most” forms. And thus now in my code for a form (or report), you can always referance, or do anything to the previous calling form.

Eg:

```
frmPrevous.Requery      ‘ requery data in calling form
```

‘ force write of data in previous form

```
if frmPrevious.Dirty = true then
   frmPrevious.Dirty = false
End if
```

‘ get name of form that called the previous form.

frmPrevious.frmPrevious.Name

So this approach provides a nice clean way to do ANYTHING to the calling form, and the name of the calling form is not hard coded.

In addition to the above, this also means you do NOT have to launch the form as “dialog” which of course not only stops calling code, but prevents use of ribbon or custom menus etc.

So what this means you have to place the “additional” code you wanted to run in the calling form into a separate sub, and call that code from the report on the button you press to either close, or do whatever action is that you want.